# Docker-compose up invalid ELF header for bcrypt

Tags: node.js, nestjs, bcrypt

I was running nest backend inside a docker container, working fine til yesterday. Today I tried to restart it using docker-compose up and it give me the following error:

```
$ docker-compose up
[+] Building 0.0s (0/0)                                                   docker:default
[+] Running 2/0
 ✔ Container nest--admin-db-1       Running                                         0.0s
 ✔ Container nest--admin-backend-1  Created                                         0.0s
Attaching to nest--admin-backend-1, nest--admin-db-1
nest--admin-backend-1  |
nest--admin-backend-1  | > nest--admin@0.0.1 start:dev
nest--admin-backend-1  | > nest start --watch
nest--admin-backend-1  |
nest--admin-backend-1  | sh: 1: nest: not found
nest--admin-backend-1 exited with code 127
```

Then I tried to rebuild the backed using docker-compose build backend(volume name), but got following error:

```
$ docker-compose build backend
[+] Building 10.7s (6/10)                                                 docker:default
 => [backend internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                        0.8s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 149B                                                0.0s
 => [backend internal] load .dockerignore                                           0.5s
 => => transferring context: 78B                                                    0.0s
 => [backend internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:18.18.0             8.4s
 => [backend auth] library/node:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                 0.0s
 => [backend 1/5] FROM docker.io/library/node:18.18.0@sha256:ee0a21d64211d92d4340b  0.7s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/node:18.18.0@sha256:ee0a21d64211d92d4340b225c556e  0.7s
 => CANCELED [backend internal] load build context                                  0.5s
 => => transferring context: 115.89kB                                               0.0s
failed to solve: Canceled: context canceled
```

I'm using win10 as host. Any idea what's going wrong?
Here is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
services:
  backend:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 8000:3000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.43
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: admin
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - .dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 33066:3306
```

And Docker file:

```
FROM node:18.18.0

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD npm run start:dev
```

After moving @nestjs/cli to dependencies and adding /node-modules to my .dockerignore file, now i got the following error:

> Error: /app/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.n
> ode: invalid ELF header

Comment: can you share your `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml`?

Comment: Removed tags. Docker isn't the issue here. It's just the PATH within your specific image (which you've not mentioned)

Comment: @richyen, I added the required files.